# Spring Data Redis enableTransactionSupport connection not return to the pool

Tags: spring-data-redis

When I set `enableTransactionSupport` to `true`, the connection is not returned to the pool. Even when the `@Transactional` method has finished, the connection is bound to the thread, this is a big problem, how to solve it? I use spring-data-redis 2.7.2 and jedis 2.8.1

```
<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxTotal" value="${redis.maxTotal}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${redis.maxIdle}" />
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="${redis.maxWaitMillis}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${redis.testOnBorrow}" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="jedisFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${redis.host}" /> 
    <property name="port" value="${redis.port}" />
    <property name="usePool" value="true" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisFactory" />
    <property name="enableTransactionSupport" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultSerializer">
    <bean class="com.wd.ics.util.CustomRedisSerializer" /> </property>    
</bean>
```

the connection is not release to the redis pool,if i not use `enableTransactionSupport`, it is ok. But it do not support the `@Transactional` of Spring.how to solve it?

Comment: Could you please post your code? Thank you.

Comment: Hi. You can edit your own question, so that all the info is there, and it more readable. Please take the comments just as if they could be removed eventually without loosing info (e.g. asking for clarifications, things you don't understand, etc). Thank you.

Comment: ok,i have write the SessionCallback to solve it!!! it work well,that's all,thanks.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question if you like, so that it serves as a reference for other pepole. Thanks.

Comment: @Jair泰国事业部 can you please explain what you did exactly to fix this issue? I am currently facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind the bind connection like this.

```
RedisConnectionUtils.unbindConnection(redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
```

And if you use the jedis. It will return the connection to the pool.

```
if (pool != null) {
        if (!broken) {
            // reset the connection
            try {
                if (dbIndex > 0) {
                    jedis.select(0);
                }
                pool.returnResource(jedis);
                return;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                DataAccessException dae = convertJedisAccessException(ex);
                if (broken) {
                    pool.returnBrokenResource(jedis);
                } else {
                    pool.returnResource(jedis);
                }
                throw dae;
            }
        } else {
            pool.returnBrokenResource(jedis);
            return;
        }
    }
```